# How to generate N random ints from 0 to num in C# efficiently?

Tags: c#

I was able to write a function that can generate "unique && random" integers within a range. But this in n<sup>2</sup>. I'm using it for 6 random ints at one place and 30 random ints at other, so how can we improve it if there's a need to improve it?

```
    private int[] genRands(int max, int totalRandomIntsRequired)
    {
        int[] nums = new int[totalRandomIntsRequired];

        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < totalRandomIntsRequired; i++)
        {
            nums[i] = r.Next(0, max + 1);

            for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if(nums[i] == nums[j])
                {
                    nums[i] = r.Next(0, max + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return nums;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you looping twice?

Comment: Do not use an array to store the already created values.

Comment: oh sorry, i thought it'll notify me of any comment. I'm looping twice to check if there aren't any duplicates.
What should I use in place of array then @Steve?

Comment: If `max` is close to `total` you may be better off shuffling the numbers 0..max-1 and then taking the first `total` of them.

Comment: max is atleast 200. total is always 24.

Comment: `Random.Next(0,max)` is always exclusive the `max` value so `genRands(4,4)` will be (0,1,2,3) in any order

Comment: Even with your double-loop, you're not safe. When you reset `nums[i]` inside your inner loop, you're not guaranteed that the value you've now chosen wasn't a value you've already seen at a higher `j` value.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i figured that out when i was staring at the question after posting it but the answers started coming so quickly that i forgot to mention that. but i think fubo's answer solves that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is a approach with a `HashSet` which does not allow duplicates and as a efficient internal duplicate check.

```
public static int[] genRands(int total, int max)
{
    if (max < total)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
    Random _random = new Random();
    HashSet<int> Result = new HashSet<int>();
    while (Result.Count < total)
    {
        Result.Add(_random.Next(0, max));
    }
    return Result.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused in what you are asking, if you just need to generate 6 or n random numbers, why loop twice? Either way you can try out this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rands = genRands(100, 6);
            foreach (var num in rands.Select((n, i) => new { i= i + 1, n }))
            { Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] {1}", num.i, num.n));};
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static List<int> genRands(int max, int total)
        {
            var nums = new List<int>();
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
                nums.Add(r.Next(0, max));
            return nums;
        }
    }
}
```

It should output something like this

```
[1] 45
[2] 29
[3] 40
[4] 75
[5] 29
[6] 57
```

Comment: there can be duplicates within `nums` - OP wants _unique && random_

Comment: they need to be unique as well. That's why i'm looping twice, checking in each iteration if this number is not in the array already.

Comment: Oh I didn't see the unique requirement in the initial question. My bad